# Android Game Memory Mgm't

Tags: android, oop

I have a problem regards the memory management of my game on Android 2.2.
There are several possible theories I could enumerate that could cause this:

1. Loading bitmaps on a non-cache idea (I load it using the item's bitmap object)
2. I didn't use the Bitmap.recycle()
3. Because I'm using OOP design, I just using Iterator.remove() instead of nulling it
4. Bitmap actual size reached 300KB [major cause of lag]
5. MediaPlayer object was used to play audio animation
6. Too much memory overhead before game-play [everything is already loaded]

Though enumerating the said items can be done by adjusting some of my style of coding it, my main concern is how can I code properly a game on Android 2.2 without causing the major lag on the phone.

- What analogy should I consider?
- Should I use OpenGL (but my game is only a 2D accelerometer game)?
- Should I only get the objects I need from the database (but that would mean leaving the access to the table open throughout the game)?
- Or others, kindly post your answer.

Your response is highly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: This very vague question, its not clear what your are asking

Comment: I would say the lagging problem is what matters most.

Comment: I guess if I were to write an answer that was just as specific and clear as your question it would be: "Don't write code that lags"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented on by slayton, your question is not very focused.  It appears that you are concerned with the memory footprint and performance of your app but unsure of where to start.  I would recommend profiling your app.  Find out where it spends most of its time processing or allocating memory.  Then work on making that part of your code more efficient.

The Android SDK includes a nice profiling tool documented here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

Lagging how? If it stutters every now and then, it could be the GC, meaning you need to check your allocations. You can use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) to check. (For example, there are hidden allocations when you use a foreach style loop. Those allocations need to be cleaned up, and the GC will run right in the middle of your code. Using the old `for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)` prevents that.)

On the other hand, if it's constant lag (touch the screen, wait ~200ms for response) it could be the order of operations, especially any draw operations. Drawing `Bitmap` to `Canvas` is slow, and using OpenGL may help. You may also need to restructure so that any input has a visual response on the very next draw.

In any case, it helps if you have a specific problem. Any code, profiling measurements, etc help us come up with better answers.

Comment: Drawing Bitmap to Canvas would be one of the main cause. Understanding how OpenGL works might take me time to do so. Would it resolve if I'm going to resize the image i.e. 300kb [320x480] to 150kb [160x240] then resize it on the canvas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. In my experience, drawing a couple of bitmaps or drawing a couple dozen was about the same. I think the limit is the whole `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()`, `surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost()` process.